# Does pointer to pointer dereference has any performance impact?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Which program is better?

Does storing pointer reference in a local copy make a considerable difference if dereferencing is done often?

Program1:

```
void program1(){
for (int i =0; i<1000; i++)
    a[i] = ptr1->ptr2->ptr3->structure[i].variable;
}
```

Program2

```
void program2(){
int* local_copy = ptr1->ptr2;
for (int i =0; i<1000; i++)
   a[i] = local_copy->structure[i].variable;
}
```

Comment: The only way to know is to check the assembly to see if the produce the same code or to write a benchmark and get some performance numbers.  I would think an optimizing compiler would make both the same.

Comment: second program won't compile because of "typos", type mismatches: `local_copy` is not an `int*`.

Comment: It's impossible to say without the full code. For example, the compiler may not be able to tell that `a[i]` does not alias `ptr1` or `ptr2`, or variables may be marked as volatile or atomic. In general, it's reasonable to assume that the compile can lift obvious things out of loops, but you need to look yourself what's happening if this is performance critical code.

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages. Tag only the language your code is written in(related to).

Comment: In general every indirection is overhead.  In practice always measure before you assume something is your bottleneck. Some compilers might even catch some loop invariants and pull them out of the loop for you.  Fun and insightful video : [What has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: Code describes behaviour. The compiler takes the code, interprets the behaviour it describes, and tries to produce the most optimal list of instructions to produce the behaviour that it can.

Comment: @user4581301 Which it does ;)

Comment: That's true. I walked into the Yoda Conundrum. There is no try.

Comment: Write straight forward code.  If it does not meet requirements in release build with optimizations, profile the code to figure out exactly where the bottle neck(s) are, and optimize appropriately.  Don't write your code as if every line must be fully optimized at the source code level - compilers are much smarter than we are.

Answer (score 2):

Small test : https://godbolt.org/z/Pesfsoq1z

Inner loop :

```
a[n] = ptr1->ptr2->ptr3->structure[n].variable;
```

Compiles to :

```
mov     rcx, qword ptr [rax + 32]
mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], rcx
movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rax]
movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rax + 16]
movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp + 16], xmm1
movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp], xmm0
xor     ebx, ebx
```

And inner loop :

```
a[n] = p->structure[n].variable;
```

Compiles to :

```
mov     rcx, qword ptr [rax + 32]
mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], rcx
movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rax]
movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rax + 16]
movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp + 16], xmm1
movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp], xmm0
xor     ebx, ebx
```

Which is the exact same assembly, so the answer to your question (for clang 15) is : **It doesn't matter**. (The compiler has spotted the invariants and optimized)

PS. I used unique pointers to not have memory leaks. It is a small overhead to pay

Comment: This is a better demonstration than I was going to say, "a chain of reference is just a bunch of plus or minus math ops to calculate the target address. so, it doesn't matter."

Comment: Well there is all kinds of subtle details still left, like : will all the indirections lead to extra cache misses etc... (because data is more spread out through system memory) . But that's why you always need to measure. Sometimes restructuring your datastructures has more influence on performance then how you write your loops ;)